# What is the grammatical name for a sentence whose predicate is a complete sentence?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, descriptive-grammar

What is the grammatical name for a sentence whose predicate is a complete sentence with a subject and a verb?

As in the following example:

> Those who stole money from the company — we will fire them; those who revealed the crime — we will reward them.

I know this example can be inverted to read:

> We will fire those who stole money from the company and we will reward those who revealed the crime.

But I want to know the linguistic term for the type of sentence I am asking about.

Answer (score 1):

Moving a constituent to the beginning of the sentence to give it prominence is called [fronting](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/English_clause_syntax#/Fronting_and_zeroing) (or preposing). *Fronting* is one aspect of [information structure](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Information_structure) (or information packaging).

*The Oxford Dictionary of English Grammar* (p166) has the following explanation of *fronting*:

> The placing of a constituent at the beginning of a sentence, clause,
>   etc., often to achieve a certain effect.
>
> English sentences typically begin with a subject, but other functional
>   elements—object, predicative complement, adverbial, and even part of
>   the predicate—can be placed at the beginning, typically for
>   information structuring reasons, for instance in order to mark the
>   topic/theme.

The specific construction you are asking about:

> Those who stole money from the company — we will fire them

as opposed to:

> Those who stole money from the company we will fire.

includes *them* as a kind of [resumptive pronoun](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Resumptive_pronoun).

There may be a specific term of which I am unaware for this kind of fronting/information structure.